# Regular expression to skip all <html> tags and search in remaining text

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I am using MongoDB where I have a collection named **Companies**, and it is having documents as following-

```
    {
        "_id":1,
        "name": "Innovative Software pvt. limited 1",
        "description": "This is a software company"
    }

    {
        "_id":2,
        "name": "Innovative Software pvt. limited 2",
        "description": "This is a software,company with <img src='' class='' alt='company logo' /> symbol"
    }

    {
        "_id":3,
        "name": "Innovative Software pvt. limited 3",
        "description": "This is a software, company with <img src='' class='' alt='company,logo' /> symbol"
    }

    {
        "_id":4,
        "name": "Innovative Software pvt. limited 4",
        "description": "This is a software, company with,<img src='' class='' alt='company, logo' /> symbol"
    }
```

Now I want a regular expression to find all companies where 
**decsription** field satisfy the following condition-

**1-** No space between a comma and the letter/number/image that follows it.
**2-** It shouldn't include content writte inside img tags.

So in my case I want the output of following documents-
_id:2("description": "This is a softwar**e,c**ompany with...,

_id:4("description": "This is a software, company wit**h,<**..

I want a query something like-

```
db.Companies.find({description:{$regex:'regular expression'}})
```

Can it be achieved in the query itself, or I need to write the logic inside code itself. I am using pymongo.

Comment: You can use JSONPATH instead

Comment: Sujith - How to use that?

Comment: Refer : http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: Sujith Thanks! But it seems like it requires an library to be added. I want to achieve it without using any extra lib.

Comment: What is your 2nd condition  ( It shouldn't include content writte inside tags. )?

Comment: It is img tags.I updated the question.

Comment: I still don't understand the second requirement. The first one is `,\S`.

Comment: @thg435 - The 2nd requirement is that it shouldn't fetch record(if written inside html tags) where 1st condition is satisfied. See eg for _id : 3. Here desciption is - This is a software, company with <img src='' class='' alt='company,logo' /> symbol. Now "alt='company,logo'" is satisfying the 1st condition, but since it is written inside <img> tag so I don't want to fetch it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/"description"\s*:\s*"(?:[^<'"]|\\")+?,(?=[<a-z]).+"/gi
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/bN3uY7

Comment: Thanks Alex! you rocks!! :)